# Velocity Template append variable to url

Tags: velocity

I'm trying to attached a velocity variable to a url like so :

```
 /url/$imagename.png
```

This just display $imagename and not the variable.  How to I display the variable without adding white-space?

Comment: please provide complete code

Answer (score 2):

make sure your url is not within the curly braces and then simply add the variable on

like so

```
/url/${imagename}.png
```